# Finding Mandatory fields

Tags: core-service, schema

I am trying to list all mandatory fields in a Schema via a custom Core Service project. I don't see that field in the `SchemaFieldsData` (or probably I am overlooking it).

Is there a way I can determine if a field is configured as mandatory or not?

```cs
SchemaFieldsData schemaFieldsData = Client.ReadSchemaFields(txtSchTCMURI, true, null);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To elaborate on Rob's answer, the code to add to yours would be something like:

```cs
SchemaFieldsData schemaFieldsData = Client.ReadSchemaFields(txtSchTCMURI, true, null);

foreach (var schemaField in schemaFieldsData.Fields)
{
    bool isMandatory = schemaField.MinOccurs > 0;
    // Do something with isMandatory
}
```

or perhaps

```cs
var mandatoryFields = schemaFieldsData.Fields.Where(field => field.MinOccurs > 0);
```

Comment: Thank you David, Rob's answer was helpful, but was waiting for a better answer as he suggested.. Thanks for the code snippet though :)..

Comment: Not sure how much simpler you can get than just loading the schema fields and sorting through them, but ok :)

Comment: Yes, this is simpler.. but as he mentioned he was still doubtful about that approach.. anyways, thanks all :)

Comment: Hmm... looks like I accidentally downvoted this. Now SE won't let me undo it unless there's an edit. Please accept this virtual +1 as recompense.

Comment: @HarishA This is a better answer and David deserves the points really!

Answer (score 6):

I think you need to look at the `MinOccurs` and `MaxOccurs` on each field. `MinOccurs` will be `1` for mandatory fields. Remember the Schema is an XSD.

There's probably a simpler way but I've never done this before.

See here for example of creating the fields:
http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-5A946CBF-36D3-4D11-BE04-4901F9ED88E3